# Run second X server from within X as a systemd service

Tags: debian, x11, xorg, systemd, x-server

I want to start a second X server from within an already running X session.

Until debian 8 I can edit `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` and change line `allowed_users=console` to `allowed_users=anybody`. This allows me as an unprivileged user to run X from within X. X is a setuid wrapper for Xorg.

Things changed in debian 9, X is no longer a setuid wrapper, instead privileges needed by X are ruled by systemd. The file `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` does not exist anymore.

It is possible to restore legacy behaviour with package `xserver-xorg-legacy`. Then `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` has to contain the lines

```
allowed_users=anybody
needs_root_rights=yes
```

Another possibility is to switch to one of tty1...tty6 and to run X with `xinit xterm -- :1 vt1` while vt1...vt6 must comply to tty1...tty6. (tty8...tty12 / vt8...vt12 are not available anymore.)

I want to avoid using legacy settings and to avoid switching to console. I want back the possiblity of `xinit xterm -- :1 vt8`.

How can I setup systemd to allow unprivileged users to start a second X server from within an already running X?

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant to your query; have you looked into Xephyr with different permissions? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xephyr

Answer (score 4):

**I recommend not using `xinit`, because it is vulnerable**.  Use `startx` instead.  `xinit` appears to be written to accept X connections from any user ID, without warning or documentation.  `startx` appears to fix this.  I do not know why this situation is tolerated, or how it happened in the first place.

As root:

```
systemd-run --property PAMName=login \
            --property User=my-user \
            --property StandardInput=tty \
            --property TTYPath=/dev/tty8 \
            sh -c 'chvt 8 && startx /usr/bin/xterm -- :1'
```

The magic is in defining `PAMName=`, to open a PAM session, and associating that session with the specific TTY.  This gets [pam_systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html) to do what you want.  I spoofed `login` - though technically you're supposed to define a new PAM "service name" in case it needs some special treatment.

So you can write a script which performs the desired command.  Then grant access to run that script as root, using `sudo`.

If you use SELinux, you'll have to fight that as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556282/how-to-run-startx-from-non-login-e-g-ssh-session-on-linux). I tried your method and it works great! Here's [the script I wrote](http://ix.io/23XE). I'm not sure which of the many duplicates of this question should be closed though